# Changing Theme Color in Windows 10 store App

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10

//This is the code in App.Xaml.cs

```
private void DetermineAppTheme()
            {

            bool value = true;

            if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("IsLightTheme"))
            {
                value = ((bool)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["IsLightTheme"]);
            }
            if (value == true)
            {
                this.RequestedTheme = (ApplicationTheme)ElementTheme.Light;
            }
            else
            {
                this.RequestedTheme = (ApplicationTheme)ElementTheme.Dark;
            }
        }
```

This is the code that I was previously using to change color in a Windows 8/8.1 Store app but unfortunately this is not working on windows 10 app.

In my settings page I am changing the state of theme on click using these lines  of code

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["IsLightTheme"] = false;
        MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Please restart the Application so that Theme change can take place");
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
```

Why is this not changing the color from white to black, I don't understand. This works fine if implemented on a Windows 8 app.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in your App.xaml.cs file, you're setting value = true; and then if(value) { // set light theme }

You need to set light theme if value is false.

Comment: When I click the button to change theme color it saves the state to false. and when the app is re- launched it should change the color which it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I myself found the solution. First of all

```
 this.RequestedTheme = (ApplicationTheme)ElementTheme.Light;
```

has to be changed to

```
this.RequestedTheme = (ApplicationTheme)ElementTheme.Default;
```

and in app.xaml Requested Theme has to be removed. and then this code will change the theme/